# UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Running a Jenkinsfile test and the following stage is returning `UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List`

```
stage('Checkout') {
    steps {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [name: '*/master'], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], 
                [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'targetDir']], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'jenkinsserviceaccount',
                url: 'https://bitbucket.company.net/scm/moak/myTestRepo.git']]])
    }
}
```

I did change some names after the fact for posting here, but the above was created using the Jenkins snippet generator.  Any idea on what may be going wrong with the checkout?

Here is more of the exception I am seeing in the Jenkins console.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:402)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:341)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:282)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate 
    {extensions=[{$class=CleanBeforeCheckout}, {$class=RelativeTargetDirectory, relativeTargetDir=stateStore}], 
    submoduleCfg=[], 
    userRemoteConfigs=[{credentialsId=jenkinsserviceaccount, url=https://bitbucket.hylandqa.net/scm/moak/hyland-statestore.git}], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations=false, 
    branches={name=*/master}} 
for GitSCM(userRemoteConfigs: UserRemoteConfig(url: String, name: String, refspec: String, credentialsId: String)[], 
    branches: BranchSpec(name: String)[], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: boolean, 
    submoduleCfg: org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class hudson.plugins.git.SubmoduleConfig[], 
    browser: GitRepositoryBrowser{AssemblaWeb(repoUrl: String) | BitbucketWeb(repoUrl: String) | CGit(repoUrl: String) | FisheyeGitRepositoryBrowser(repoUrl: String) | 
        GitBlitRepositoryBrowser(repoUrl: String, projectName: String) | GitLab(repoUrl: String, version: String) | GitList(repoUrl: String) | GitWeb(repoUrl: String) | 
        GithubWeb(repoUrl: String) | Gitiles(repoUrl: String) | GitoriousWeb(repoUrl: String) | GogsGit(repoUrl: String) | KilnGit(repoUrl: String) | 
        Phabricator(repoUrl: String, repo: String) | RedmineWeb(repoUrl: String) | RhodeCode(repoUrl: String) | Stash(repoUrl: String) | 
        TFS2013GitRepositoryBrowser(repoUrl: String) | ViewGitWeb(repoUrl: String, projectName: String)}, 
        gitTool: String, extensions: GitSCMExtension{AuthorInChangelog() | 
        BuildChooserSetting(buildChooser: BuildChooser{AncestryBuildChooser(maximumAgeInDays: int, ancestorCommitSha1: String) | 
        DefaultBuildChooser() | InverseBuildChooser()}) | ChangelogToBranch(options: ChangelogToBranchOptions(compareRemote: String, compareTarget: String)) | 
        CheckoutOption(timeout: int) | CleanBeforeCheckout() | CleanCheckout() | 
        CloneOption(shallow: boolean, noTags: boolean, reference: String, timeout: int, depth?: int, honorRefspec?: boolean) | 
        DisableRemotePoll() | GitLFSPull() | IgnoreNotifyCommit() | LocalBranch(localBranch: String) | MessageExclusion(excludedMessage: String) | 
        PathRestriction(includedRegions: String, excludedRegions: String) | PerBuildTag() | 
        PreBuildMerge(options: UserMergeOptions(mergeTarget: String, fastForwardMode?: GitPluginFastForwardMode[FF, FF_ONLY, NO_FF], mergeRemote?: String, mergeStrategy?: Strategy[DEFAULT, RESOLVE, RECURSIVE, OCTOPUS, OURS, SUBTREE, RECURSIVE_THEIRS])) | 
        PruneStaleBranch() | RelativeTargetDirectory(relativeTargetDir: String) | ScmName(name: String) | 
        SparseCheckoutPaths(sparseCheckoutPaths: SparseCheckoutPath(path: String)[]) | 
        SubmoduleOption(disableSubmodules: boolean, recursiveSubmodules: boolean, trackingSubmodules: boolean, reference: String, timeout: int, parentCredentials: boolean) | 
        UserExclusion(excludedUsers: String) | UserIdentity(name: String, email: String) | WipeWorkspace()}[])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see this error, because `branches` key needs to hold a map nested in a list. So it should be:

```
branches: [[name: '*/master']]
```

instead

```
branches: [name: '*/master']
```

> *Source: [https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#code-checkout-code-general-scm](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#code-checkout-code-general-scm_)*

Full stage then looks like this:

```
stage('Checkout') {
    steps {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], 
                [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'targetDir']], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'jenkinsserviceaccount',
                url: 'https://bitbucket.company.net/scm/moak/myTestRepo.git']]])
    }
}
```

Regarding the error you see - workflow plugin uses Groovy's ability to cast `Map` to another type. It works if all map keys map to a class fields correctly, e.g. they have to store the same type. When `branches` stores a `Map` instead `List<Map>`, the whole map cannot be cast to an object that represents SCM configuration.